# How do I use CASE conditions with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I guess have a simple problem with the CASE condition in MySQL, because I do not get it working, always get an syntax-error.

My current problem: I have one table with a list of id's and a name. Depending of the name I need to adress another table and join / get data from these table.
But it does not work with my CASE, so I just tried a super simple thing, but even this I can not get to run :-(

```
SELECT * FROM
CASE
WHEN 1=1 THEN `table_a`
ELSE `table_b`
END CASE;
```

I am using MySQL Version 5.5

Can someone help me out?

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CASE will need to be After the SELECT but before the FROM

```
SELECT CASE WHEN a.Name = 'Luke' THEN b.column WHEN a.Name = 'Sarah' THEN c.column ELSE d.column END AS ColumnName
FROM Table1 AS a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 AS b ON a.column = b.column
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table3 AS c ON a.column = c.column
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table4 AS d ON a.column = d.column
```

The problem i think you're trying to solve though, it to use one table to join on if a name equals something and then join to a different table if a name equals something else. This is not going to work how you want it because of a variety of reasons. If you want to get all table's data based on a name then you could have all the results come out in a wide result set.

```
SELECT a.name, b.*, c.*, d.* 
FROM Table1 AS a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 AS b ON a.column = b.column AND a.name = 'Luke'
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table3 AS c ON a.column = c.column AND a.Name = 'Sarah'
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table4 AS d ON a.column = d.column AND a.NAME NOT IN ('Sarah', 'Luke')
```

athough this result would look something like (excuse the *'s)

NAME, b.Heading1,... b.HeadingN, c.Heading1,... c.HeadingN,NAME, d.Heading1, ... d.HeadingN
Luke*****Data,*********Data**********NULL***********NULL**************NULL************NULL
Sarah****NULL,*********NULL*******Data*************Data***************NULL************NULL
Nancy***NULL,*********NULL********NULL***********NULL**************Data*************Data

In any case, it might be beneficial to add more information including sample data so we can have a look.

Comment: Hi @Spasticmonkey, I answer that late because I was thinking about your comment and found out, that you are totally right - it makes not really sense what I was trying to do! I will think about a redesign. So your answer really helped me. Thank you !! :)

Answer (score 1):

`case` is an expression that returns a scalar value.  It cannot be used to select tables.

If your tables have the same columns in the same order, you could do:

```
select a.*
from table_a a
where 1 = 1
union all
select b.*
from table_b b
where 1 <> 1;
```

An example of its use would be:

```
select a.*, (case when 1=1 then 'yes' else 'no' end) as col
from table_a a;
```

Comment: Aaah, thanks a lot!!! Yes, that's explaining it. No, my tables all have different columns. I just want to select those columns in them, which are simular in all tables. So the idea is: I select my master-table, and for each row I look for the name, use any *magic* to select the correct table for it and grab the columns.

Comment: @K.S. . . . You should ask another question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: OK, thank you. But is my topic question unclear and not useful??